# How to drop dictionaries with NaN values from list

Tags: python, dictionary, nan

This seems like a fairly simple thing but I haven't been able to find an answer for it here (yet).

I have a list of dictionaries, and some of the dictionaries in the list have NaN values. I just need to drop any dictionary from the list if it has a NaN value in it.

I've tried it a few different ways myself. Here's one attempt with filter and a lambda function, which got a TypeError ("must be real number, not dict_values," which makes sense):

```
from math import isnan

def remove_dictionaries_missing_data(list_of_dictionaries):
    return list(filter(lambda dictionary: not math.isnan(dictionary.values()), \
                                          list_of_dictionaries))
```

I also tried it with a couple nested loops and some code I really wasn't sure about and got the same error:

```
from math import isnan

def remove_dictionaries_missing_data(list_of_dictionaries):
    cleaned_list = []
    for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries:
        if not math.isnan(dictionary[value] for value in dictionary.values()):
            cleaned_list.append(dictionary)
    return cleaned_list
```

... and finally with just a list comprehension (same error):

```
from math import isnan
def remove_movies_missing_data(movies):
    return [movie for movie in movies if not math.isnan(movie.values())]
```

EDIT:

Here's a sample of the list I'm working with:

```
[{'year': 2013,
  'imdb': 'tt2005374',
  'title': 'The Frozen Ground',
  'test': 'nowomen-disagree',
  'clean_test': 'nowomen',
  'binary': 'FAIL',
  'budget': 19200000,
  'domgross': nan,
  'intgross': nan,
  'code': '2013FAIL',
  'budget_2013$': 19200000,
  'domgross_2013$': nan,
  'intgross_2013$': nan,
  'period code': 1.0,
  'decade code': 1.0},
 {'year': 2011,
  'imdb': 'tt1422136',
  'title': 'A Lonely Place to Die',
  'test': 'ok',
  'clean_test': 'ok',
  'binary': 'PASS',
  'budget': 4000000,
  'domgross': nan,
  'intgross': 442550.0,
  'code': '2011PASS',
  'budget_2013$': 4142763,
  'domgross_2013$': nan,
  'intgross_2013$': 458345.0,
  'period code': 1.0,
  'decade code': 1.0},
... ]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To help us help you, please edit your post and add a sample of the dictionary you are processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dictionary.values()` is a generator for all the values in the dictionary. You need to call `math.isnan()` on the individual values. You can use `any()` to do this:

```
def remove_dictionarries_missing_data(list_of_dictionaries):
    return [d for d in list_of_dictionaries 
             if not any(isinstance(val, float) and math.isnan(val) for val in d.values())]
```

Comment: Am I wrong or is some() not a Python method? When I used some I got an error saying name "some" is not defined. I tried using any() in a list comprehension but got an error message (but a new one, "must be real number, not str").

Comment: `math.isnan()` can only be called on numbers. I assumed your dictionary only contained numbers, but some of them are NaN.

Comment: I've added code to check whether the value is a `float` before calling `math.isnan()`

Comment: @Kristian:  Python has no built-in `some()` function.

Comment: @martineau It was my mistake in the first version of my answer.